# Superscript issues

Tags: ee2

I'm having trouble getting  to work in the content editing area for EE 2.4.0. Put it in the source, switch back to text, looks fine but after submitting, just shows up as a regular number in both Chrome and FF. I would just use ³ for example, but I've got a 4 author paper I need to reference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a styling issue? Try explicitly styling the sup. E.g.

```
sup {
  vertical-align: .6em;
  font-size: 65%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your CSS reset code is removing the default styling for the sup tag.